# pytorch: reverse indexing

Tags: arrays, indexing, pytorch

I have 2 torch tensors

```
a : Tensor, dim (K,)
reverse_indices: Tensor, dim (L,)
```

Where all values in `reverse_indices` are unique and sorted (but all values of `a` are not necessarily in `reverse_indices`)

I am looking for an efficient way to obtain the tensor

```
indices: Longtensor, dim (M,)
```

so that

```
reverse_indices[indices] = a[torch.isin(a, reverse_indices)]
```

(note that `reverse_indices` is **not** the output of `torch.unique`, otherwise the result would be easy to get by just passing the right result to `torch.unique`).

Answer (score 0):

OK for now I went for this, but if someone has a way to do it without creating a `K×L` matrix, I'll accept that instead.

```py
def reverse_index(a, reverse_indices):
        """
        assuming all elements in a are also in reverse_indices
        Args:
            a : Tensor, dim (K,)
            reverse_indices: Tensor, dim (L,)
        Returns:
            indices: so that ``reverse_indices[indices] = a``
        """
        a = a[torch.isin(a, reverse_indices)]
        correspondance = (a[:, None] == reverse_indices[None, :]).astype(int)
        indices = correspondance.argmax(dim=1) #works cause all of them are 0 and one is 1
        return indices
```